# ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from partially initialized module 'panel.config'

Tags: python, panel

I'm trying to import the package panel, however, when I try to do that I receive the following message:

### Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\nicol\Documents\Gist\Centrafrique Python\6. Draft_keyword frequency.ipynb Cell 2 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import hvplot.pandas
2 import holoviews as hv
4 hv.extension('bokeh')

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\hvplot_*init*_.py:8, in 
5 import textwrap
7 import param
----> 8 import holoviews as _hv
10 from holoviews import Store
12 from .converter import HoloViewsConverter

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\holoviews_*init*_.py:12, in 
8 **version** = str(param.version.Version(fpath=**file**, archive_commit="$Format:%h$",
9                                         reponame="holoviews"))
11 from . import util                                       # noqa (API import)
---> 12 from .annotators import annotate                         # noqa (API import)
13 from .core import archive, config                        # noqa (API import)
14 from .core.boundingregion import BoundingBox             # noqa (API import)

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\holoviews\annotators.py:10, in 
6 from inspect import getmro
8 import param
...
----> 9 from ..config import config
11 from .callbacks import PeriodicCallback # noqa
12 from .embed import embed_state # noqa

ImportError: cannot import name 'config' from partially initialized module 'panel.config' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\panel\config.py)

This is my code:

```
import panel as pn
pn.extension('tabulator', sizing_mode="stretch_width")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to tell because you're not showing your code, nor the full traceback to that error.

Comment: Sorry! I just put it right now!

Comment: Most likely you have 2 modules importing eachother. This should be avoided. Try to make sure your modules form a tree, and nothing imports anything "above" itself

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How could I do that?

Comment: Please edit in your full traceback, not just the error.

Comment: Did it right now! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
from panel import panel as pn
```

Comment: Thank you! But I continue having the same issue: 'cannot import name 'config' from partially initialized module 'panel.config' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\nicol\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\panel\config.py)'

Comment: Could you share your code where you are refrencing "panel.config"

Comment: The code that I showed you (above) is the only thing I run. That's the reason why I am confused.

Comment: I have tried this on my own machaine and is working fine. I would recommend uninstalling panel and updating your pip and see if that helps.

Comment: Glad to hear it! I would encourage you accept this as the answer.

Thanks